# Unresolved external symbol using static constexpr member

Tags: c++, templates, static, conditional-statements, constexpr

I'm trying to compile this (C++14) code using VC++ 2017.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <limits>

struct Templ
{
    template <typename T>
        static constexpr int value = ( std::numeric_limits<T>::min() == 0 );
};
using type = std::conditional_t<Templ::value<unsigned>, bool, double>;

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error message:

> unresolved external symbol "public: static int const Templ::value" (??$value@I@Templ@@2HB) referenced in function "void __cdecl Templ::`dynamic initializer for 'public: static int const Templ::value''(void)" (??__E??$value@I@Templ@@2HB@Templ@@YAXXZ)|

How can I correctly use `conditional_t` with a templated static constexpr member as the condition?

**Edit.** Based on Some programmer dude's answer I came up with this:

```
struct Templ
{
    template<typename T>
        struct inner
    {
        enum
        {
            value = ( std::numeric_limits<T>::min() == 0 )
        };
    };
};
using type = std::conditional_t<Templ::inner<unsigned>::value, bool, double>;
```

Comment: The error message doesn't fit with the code you show, as the error message mentions `Templ::value<double>` and you don't have it in your code. Is the code you show truly a [mcve] that generates the error you show?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude sorry, updated the code and the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't with `std::conditional_t`, but simply that even if you make the member variable `constexpr` and initialize it inline in the class, you still need to *define* it.

A simple solution, considering that your variable is a plain `int`, is to use an enumeration instead. But then you need to make the structure `Templ` a template instead:

```
template <typename T>
struct Templ
{
    enum
    {
        value = (std::numeric_limits<T>::min() == 0)
    };
};
using type = std::conditional_t<Templ<unsigned>::value, bool, double>;
```

Comment: Thanks. I wonder why it needs to be defined even if it's not odr-used (or is it?). I need the value, not the enclosing  struct to have the template argument T so I modified this a little bit. See the result in the question. Do you think it's the recommended way to accomplish this in C++14?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code on https://www.onlinegdb.com/ and it works perfectly fine.

You have issues with dependencies when you build your code. Check out "references" in your project. Libraries you depend upon must be marked. If it is an external library you ought to add a path to it.

Comment: Thanks. This code works for me with any version of GCC that I've tried (including GCC 5.4.1 on your link). My problem is specific to Visual C++ 2017. This code doesn't depend on any additional libraries.